# do salesforce provide anything like async/wait which can handle loop to wait before going to next iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Below is my salesforce lightning code, I am passing an image url to a function 'imagecheck' which in turns return if my image is valid or not. However, it is taking some time to check and my 'for' loop gets iterated to next count and thus variable 'j' value doesn't get updated and it exit out of loop. I want my 'for' loop to wait so that 'imagecheck' function can return value then it go to next iteration so that variable 'J' will also be updated. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
imagecheck: function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            resolve('success');
        }
        img.onerror = function(){
            reject('failure');
        }
        img.src = url;
    });
},
getcheck: function(component, callback) {
    var j=0;
    var myId = component.get("v.currentversionobj").Id;
    var myimages = [];
    for(var i=0;i<=j;i++)
   {

        var imageUrl = 'someprefix='+component.get("v.currentversionobj").Id+'&page='+j;   
        this.imagecheck(imageUrl).then(function(successUrl){
            j++;
            myimages.push({url:imageUrl});
            component.set("v.fileShares",myimages);
        }).catch(function(errorUrl){

            });
   }

}
```

Comment: Please remove it from duplicate as  some code differ in terms of Salesforce and javascript and will have different solution @Adrian Larson

Comment: Please make more of an effort to describe what you are trying to accomplish and where you are stuck, and to clearly differentiate this post from the other. In both posts, you simply paste a large block of code and a short sentence describing it. The questions look awfully similar.

Comment: I didn't use long post because I didn't want to complicate it.However let me just update it more since this question is really important for me.

Comment: I have updated my post, please remove it from duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: @Ruchit612 I didn't understand why did you use var i to iterate the loop when you are not using it, the same could be done using only one variable, use I or J then you don't need to increment J and wait for promise to resolve, once promise gets resolve rest of the actions will be invoked.

Comment: @Tapas so what shall i use in condition where i am checking i<=j?

Comment: Have you tried [Promise.all](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/347/javascript-promises-mastering-the-asynchronous/how-to-join-promises)?

Comment: @Aayush K No, I have not tried but I can see in the example, we are using promise.all and passing 4 job there, but in my case we don't know how many times I need to call the 'imagecheck' function

Comment: You can use an array to pass a list of promises. [https://jsfiddle.net/edtpcs4v/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/edtpcs4v/2/)